# iOS In-app-purchases and web services

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

Would Apple allow in-app-purchases which give access to a web app or online service? If, for example, I build a native iOS app version of an online service (say, a paid service similar to Readability, Squarespace etc.) would Apple allow me to use in-app-purchase to allow users to buy a subscription which would give users access to both iOS and web version of the service?

I'm asking this because, after initially thinking that this would be allowed, I found that https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf contains: "In-App Purchase items cannot be shared across applications or platforms." which seems to disallow this. However, in the same pdf, Apple explicitly say that services like buying VoIP minutes are allowed to be dealt with in in-app-purchases. Additionally, in the past Readability was rejected for not providing in-App-Purchases, seemingly suggesting that this is allowed.

Put simply, do Apple allow that after an in-app-purchases for an in-app-service is made, the same service access is given through a web version of the iOS app?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? What you decided?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is provided the service is consumed majorly through the iOS app itself. Subscriptions can work the way you are suggesting but only if if you also provide the same service as on the web in your app.